# What is the best way to create a grid with variable step?

Tags: matlab, grid

I have for example a grid  x=[0 0.1 0.2 ... 0.9 1 1.3 ... 2.2 2.25 2.30 ... 3].
What is the best way (thinking about time) how can I creat this grid?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the grid follows any particular rules.

As I see none in the example, the easiest way is to write

```
x = [0:0.1:1 1.3:0.3:2.2 2.25:0.05:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly clear on your question, would this do the trick?

```
x = 0:0.1:3;
```

If you need a full grid, try using that in combination with [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate an array with a constant step, use semicolon operator.
The syntax is `startElement:step:endElement`

For example:

```
1:5:100
```

On the other hand, if you want to generate an array with fixed amount of elements, use `linspace(startElement,endElement,amountOfElements)`

For example:

```
linspace(1,100,4)`
```